pg_cron Installed by Superuser Not Showing Records to Developers
We have pg_cron installed on our PostgreSQL 13 database. The cron schema and job table are visible to all users. When the admin user runs SELECT * FROM cron.job, it returns rows as expected. However, when any developer runs the same query, it returns 0 rows, despite the query executing successfully.
Why might developers be seeing an empty result set, and how can we resolve this issue to allow developers to see the job records?
